# Android AsynchTask data return to Activity

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have a MainActivity class from which I am calling an instance of my JsonObj class.
JsonObj extends AsynchTask. It's pasted below:

```
    public class JsonObj extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{
    int tid;
    String term;

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url[0]);
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        // Depends on your web service
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            // json is UTF-8 by default
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
//          Log.e("JSON-Test [RESULT]: ", result);
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.e("JSON-Test [exception]: ", e.toString());
        }
        finally {
            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is an AsyncTask class which I can call from any activity that will fetch and return JSON from my server.

My problem is my AsyncTask class successfully fetches my JSON but I am struggling to pass it back to my Activity.

I know the OnPostExecute function returns data on completion of my AsyncTask but all my attempts to access the data in my Activity class are not working.

I'm using `new JsonObj().execute("http://myserver/json");` to call my JsonObj class.

**How do I call OnpostExecute to directly access data my AsynchTask  fetches from my server OR what is a better solution to this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

Create an Interface that has a method called something like "onServiceFinished" which your activities that make this call implement. Then when you call your AsyncTask, pass it (this) and in your onPostExectue, call FinishedListener.onServiceFinished(var1, var2) or whatever data your passing.

Code Example: This example uses an AsyncTask to retrieve a message from the server, and when that is finished, pass back that message to the class that requested it

Interface:

```
public interface ServiceHandler {

    public abstract void onServiceFinished(JSONObject jsonObject);
}
```

Activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements ServiceHandler {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Activity stuff
        new JsonObj(this).execute("http://myserver/json");
    }

    @Override 
    public void onServiceFinished(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        // Do something with the message
    }
}
```

Asynctask:

```
public class JsonObj extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    ServiceHandler handler;

    public ChatAsync(ServiceHandler serviceHandler) {
        handler = serviceHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String...params) {
        // fetch messages from service and parse JSON
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        handler.onServiceFinished(json);
    }
}
```

The basic model is there, you'll have to modify it to fit what you're doing! Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you doing all network operation in a separate class and you want the result on the calling Activity class.

Create a method onTaskComplete(JsonObject result) on the calling Activity class.

```
public void onTaskComplete(JsonObject result) {
    //Do You Operation
    }
```

And now you need to call this method on OnPostExecute()

```
public class JsonObj extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{
    Activity _context;
    public JsonObj(Activity _context) {
        this._context = _context;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        this._context.onTaskComplete(result);
    }
}
```

At last call the AsyncTask

```
 new JsonObj(this).execute("YOUR URL");
```